# MySQL: grouping question

Tags: mysql

I have a 'stream_update' table that stores the updates users post to the groups they're subscribed to. The table has the following fields:

- id (index, auto increment)
- user_id
- group_id
- stream_update
- timestamp

Basically I'm trying to write a query that gets the last stream update for every user in each group they're subscribed to. So if a user is subscribed to 3 groups, it would get the last update he has written in each of these groups.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM stream_update GROUP BY group_id, user_id
```

This seemed to work, but it would get the oldest records not the newest. Adding "ORDER BY" to that doesn't work, since it orders the already-fetched records only.

Any idea how I can write a query for this?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select su.user_id, su.group_id, su.stream_update, su.timestamp
    from stream_update su
        inner join (select user_id, group_id, max(timestamp) as maxtime
                        from stream_update
                        group by user_id, group_id) m
            on su.user_id = m.user_id
                and su.group_id = m.group_id
                and su.timestamp = m.maxtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT id,user_id,group_id,max(stream_update),timestamp
FROM stream_update 
GROUP BY group_id, user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 select T1.user_id, t1.group_id, t2.stream_update
 from
  (     
  select  user_id, group_id, max(timestamp) as latesttimestamp
  from streamtable
  group by user_id, group_id
  )  as T1

  inner join  streamtable as T2
  on T1.user_id = T2.user_id
  and T1.group_id = T2.group_id
  and T1.latesttimestamp = T2.timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly select from a select... so do your regular select (above) and include the timestamp in the output

then wrap it in a

```
SELECT whatever-fields you want FROM (
  inner-select-statement with grouping
)
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Something like that should give you what I think you are after.